# Difference b/w scaleType:centerCrop and scaleType:centerInside

Tags: android

I've good knowledge of ImageView scaling in Android. But couldn't understand the complete diff b/w scaleTypes: centerCrop and centerInside.

Need some clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

CENTER_CROP

Added in API level 1
ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_CROP
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use this syntax: android:scaleType="centerCrop".

CENTER_INSIDE

Added in API level 1
ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_INSIDE
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use this syntax: android:scaleType="centerInside".

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

CenterCrop may crop the image and will always fill the imageview. CenterInside will not crop the image and may leave some part of the imageview not covered by the image.